# How to convert this command to a python code using Wand & ImageMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I want to convert an image so I can read it better using pyocr & tesseract.
The Command line I want to convert to python is :

```
convert pic.png -background white -flatten -resize 300% pic_2.png
```

Using python Wand I managed to resize it but I don't know how to do the flattend and the white background
My try :

```
from wand.image import Image
with Image(filename='pic.png') as image:
    image.resize(270, 33)  #Can I use 300% directly ?
    image.save(filename='pic2.png')
```

Please help

Edit, Here is the image to make tests on : 
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For resize & background. Use the following, and note that you'll need to calculate the 300% yourself.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color

with Image(filename="pic.png") as img:
  # -resize 300%
  scaler = 3
  img.resize(img.width * scaler, img.height * scaler)
  # -background white
  img.background_color = Color("white")
  img.save(filename="pic2.png")
```

Unfortunately the [c](/questions/tagged/c) method [MagickMergeImageLayers](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickMergeImageLayers) has yet to be implemented. You should author an enhancement request [with the development team](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues).

**Update**
If you want to remove the transparency, just disable the alpha channel

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="pic.png") as img:
  # Remove alpha
  img.alpha_channel = False
  img.save(filename="pic2.png")
```

**Another way**

It might just be easier to create a new image with the same dimensions as the first, and just composite the source image over the new one.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color

with Image(filename="pic.png") as img:
  with Image(width=img.width, height=img.height, background=Color("white")) as bg:
    bg.composite(img,0,0)
    # -resize 300%
    scaler = 3
    bg.resize(img.width * scaler, img.height * scaler)
    bg.save(filename="pic2.png")
```

Comment: I have added the image I'm working on, can you please test your code and see how I can make the background white whith the resize ?

Comment: @Sekai Updated answer with two options to make the background white

Comment: Let me try, and I'll be back to you